# Convert date to first day of the corresponding month from dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which is named as df

I need to convert each date to first day of that month.

```
Date          Sales
02-12-2018     1000
03-11-2019     2000
24-08-2010     3000
```

Expected output

```
Date          Sales Date2
02-12-2018     1000  01-12-2018
03-11-2019     2000  01-11-2019 
24-08-2010     3000  01-08-2010
```

and so on. I cannot seem to be able to do that in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to date and use `floor_date` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
floor_date(dmy(df$Date), 'month')
#[1] "2018-12-01" "2019-11-01" "2010-08-01"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("02-12-2018", 
"03-11-2019", "24-08-2010"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(1000L, 
2000L, 3000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to date and then format the date with "01" in the days slot.

```
format(as.Date(df$Date, "%d-%m-%Y"), "%01-%m-%Y")
# [1] "01-12-2018" "01-11-2019" "01-08-2010"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use a simple regex to do this (Using data provided by @RonakShah)

```
sub(".*?-", "01-", df$Date)
#[1] "01-12-2018" "01-11-2019" "01-08-2010"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `anydate`

```
library(anydate)
format(anydate(df$Date), "%01-%m-%Y")
```